# Checking internet connection on android

Tags: android, connection

I have the following code for checking internet connection wifi/EDGE/GPRS/3G on my application.

the code is

```
public static boolean checkConn(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
        || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
        return true;
    } else if (conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
        || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I am calling it like below :

```
if (CheckInternet.checkConn(introPage.this) == true) {
    Intent toMainPage = new Intent(introPage.this, mainPage.class);
    System.gc();
    startActivity(toMainPage);
} else if (CheckInternet.checkConn(getApplicationContext()) == false) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Sorry, No internet connectivity found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

But I am having an issue, which is that if I am connected to wifi, and I open the application, it works fine, but if I close application and turn off wifi and re-open application, it doesn't through the error of "no connection" , I need to turn off my device and then turn it on, and same case is if wifi is off, and I open application, it throws error of "no connection", and if I turn it on, still it throws the same error of "no connection", until unless I turn off and on device.

Comment: close the application by pressing home or back key?.. Coz if u close it by pressing hme then app will be in background and oncreate will not get fired

Comment: @Rahul, but why even turning on the wifi, it still gives no connection issue?

Comment: I am not sure as where you are calling this line of code...If you are just checking for this condition under activities oncreate it will be called only once...

Comment: @kaibuki this may be issue of android device, same issue i am getting in my HTC Hero, even my wireless is on

Comment: @Rahul I am calling this on each setOnClickListener() of button

Comment: @Paresh I have samsung vibrant, but even on emulator also having same issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Comment: you don't have to test if the function returns certain value since the if evaluates this. You can write your conditionals like this:

   `if(CheckInternet.checkConn(introPage.this))
    {
     ...
    }
    else
    {
     ...
    }`

Comment: Check out the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78018625/14878328)

Comment: Check out the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78018625/14878328)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Sometimes the active connection is not first in the list, or is inactive or in an error state. This is how I would do it:

```
  NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (i == null)
    return false;
  if (!i.isConnected())
    return false;
  if (!i.isAvailable())
    return false;
  return true;
```

[EDIT 1] Don't forget to add this permission in the application manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Does this help you?

Emmanuel

Comment: I was looking for checking internet connection on Android and found your answer. It looks simple and nice. But does it check 3G as well? Thx.

Comment: You have to check the type of network for this. i.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE and you can even get the subtype. i.getSubType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_*

Comment: You could also use the ConnectivityManager ==> http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/186636

Comment: Please edit this to `return i != null && i.isConnected() && i.isAvailable();`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: See I copy/pasted some code I had where I applied the "Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses" refactoring. These 3 conditions are just the beginning; there were other conditions also. That plus it's more readable.

Comment: not more readable as you can see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8343843/281545 - plus the more concise an answer the better ;)

Comment: @Emmanuel : plus, in some countries there are laws against if blocks without {}.

Comment: can any one here help me to defining what is conMgr in this code.

Comment: @Hitesh Matnani, it's the class [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). For [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.net.ConnectivityManager).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                                              .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is better:

```
if (conMgr != null) {
    NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (i != null) {
        if (!i.isConnected())
            ret = false;
        if (!i.isAvailable())
            ret = false;                
    }

    if (i == null)
        ret = false;

} else
    ret = false;
```

with the other form, if "Network i" is equal null then, check after for `!i.isConnected()` must fail (i is null).

Comment: Why not black approach instead of white approach?

Comment: You are wrong, in the other form "if(i == null)" will "return false", so skip all the rest of the checks. Also in the other way there is less CC (less anidation)

Comment: 'return' is superior than using 'else'
('else' gives cancer)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean checkNetworkStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    NetworkStatus netStatus = new NetworkStatus(connectivity, telephony);
    if (netStatus.isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
        Log.e(" in checkNetworkStatus()", "network available");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.e(" in checkNetworkStatus()", "no network");
        return false;
    }
}
```

wifi-

---

```
void chkStatus() {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (i == null)
            return false;
          if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
          if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
          return true;

    }
```

and this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following code :

```
   public class NetworkCheckDemo extends Activity
 {
TextView tvstatus;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tvstatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtviewstatus);
    ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tvstatus.setText("Network Available");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tvstatus.setText("Network Not Available");
      }
    }
  }
```

Add below 3 permissions in Android Manifest File.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I used to check if I have connectivity, don't forget to check if the NetworkInfo is null or not because on tablet where mobile data connectivity is not provided, the NetworkInfo for TYPE_MOBILE return null.

```
public static boolean collectionAllowed(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    State mobile = NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED;
    if ( mobileInfo != null) {
        mobile = mobileInfo.getState();
    }
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    State wifi = NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED;
    if ( wifiInfo != null) {
        wifi = wifiInfo.getState();
    }
    boolean dataOnWifiOnly = (Boolean) PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(
                    "data_wifi_only", true);
    if ((!dataOnWifiOnly && (mobile.equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) || wifi
            .equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)))
            || (dataOnWifiOnly && wifi.equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

same as the approved answer but in short :

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info != null && info.isConnected() && info.isAvailable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome [gist by emil2k](https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5130324) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Connectivity {
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }

    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                return false; // ~25 kbps 
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```