# How to check Internet Connection for every processing in Android?

Tags: android

In my application, most of the processing in all Activity need to connect to Server to get data.
So, where should I check the Internet connection?
Is there any methods that can tell me when the connection is unavailable?
Finally, how to implement it? Is there any API for handle this case?

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086159/checking-internet-connection-on-android

Comment: For the check the internet connection Go through this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12038094/1263679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// just checks if network connectivity is available 
public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) return true;
    return false;           
}//end method
```

Comment: so, where should I call this and what can I do if connection return false?

Comment: that's a whole new question...you call this when you need it, if it returns false you know there's no connection...

Answer (score 0):

use the `ConnectivityManager` class and `Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)` method.
More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html