# How to show a connection's window on Android?

Tags: android, connection, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking internet connection on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086159/checking-internet-connection-on-android)

How to show a connection's window on Android when you are not connected even wifi or 3g? Like on Skype app, that detect that you are not connected to the internet. Thnx!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener to receive the connection status. Through wifi recevier you can get the status whenever is connects and disconnects and for mobile data connection you can receive through phone state listener. This links will help you you to track the same.

[Phone state listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

[Wifi listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362314/wifi-connect-disconnect-listener)