# Android - Detecting end of stream as opposed to connection error in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

While listening to a 1 hour mp3 stream, if a user loses connections (or changes from WIFI to 3G and the connection "Drops" for a second) we've noticed that MediaPlayer continues to play the content it has buffered.  Once it runs out of buffered content, if it's not completed to the end of the file, I would have assumed it fires an Error event, but instead it changes state to PLAYBACK_COMPLETE. How can we figure out if the end of playback was due to an error in the connection (loss of connection) or actual playback completion? The only thing I've been able to come up with is to check currentPostion vs totalDuration when MediaPlayer changes state to PLAYBACK_COMPLETE. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it did not fire an [`onError()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) event, you can try registering an [`OnBufferingUpdateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) and check if the buffering percentage reaches 100%. If the connection is lost, on playback completion the percentage would be less than 100%.

Comment: The problem with using buffer percent (other than differences in device implementations) is the fact that these are MP3s with long durations (1-3 hours or more) and buffer percent is almost always less than 100%.

Comment: @StackOverflowed You mean even when buffering is complete, you don't get 100% in the `OnBufferingUpdateListener` callback?

Comment: I mean if the mp3 is 5 hours in length, it may have buffered 4 hours into the mp3 when network connectivity loss occurs.

Comment: @StackOverflowed Exactly. So in this case the last call to `OnBufferingUpdateListener` would be less than 100%, which indicates a network loss when playback is completed. It should reach 100% only if the buffering is complete. I don't get the problem with this method that you're trying to explain.

Comment: I'm saying it's natural for buffering not to reach 100% before there is a network issue.

Comment: The bounty was about to run out so I awarded it to you, even though no one really fully answered my question (Why may be unanswerable).

Answer (score 2):

It is really difficult to know this. I think your currentPosition & totalDuration approach is great, but I suggest you to listen for the network state of the device, as well. If the connection to the server drops caused by the client, you can know that in this way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086159/checking-internet-connection-on-android) might help

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that you have a [`OnErrorListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) implemented and inside this onError method you have to return true value. If you return a false value from this method but there was an error in that case media player fires [`OnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) onCompletion method.